# How to open a exe file in the center of the screen?

Tags: java, jframe, exe

I have created a java application that opens a `.exe` file(like notepad) on clicking a button.

How do I make that `.exe` file open in the center of the screen?

Or how do I fix the frame size of that `.exe` file?

Comment: How are opening the exe?

Comment: You need to get a handle to the processes window and the modify it's properties.  Do some research into JNI/JNA

Comment: I wonder why you want to do this though. Some users might have multiple screens and won't like their applications jumping around because you want to move them somewhere.